# Combining CNN and LSTM model dosn't work for image classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm, image-classification

I am new in deep learning, i want to compbine CNN and LSTM for image classification task (5 classes). I have edited this code:

```
    number_of_images=1887;
    nb_epoch=10;
    batch_size=100;
    # image shape = (256,256,3)

    cnn = Sequential()
    # define CNN model
    cnn.add((Conv2D(1, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(256,256,3))))
    cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    cnn.add(Flatten())
    # define LSTM model
    model= Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(None,256, 256,3)))
    model.add(LSTM(number_of_images))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10,validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I have this error message when execute model.fit():

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_20" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1887, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 256, 256, 3)
```

Any suggestion please

i tray to combine CNN (feature extrastion) and LSTM (sequence modelisation) for image classification task. after several attempts, I can't fix the model. There is a probleme of input and output dimensions

Answer (score 0):

there are a few correction need to be done for your networks is complied.

1. The shape input of the networks matches the input types and dimensions.
2. Your input is very large and sizes 256 x 256 which expects of a lot of details different, you need to transform it, label, remark or create significant input if you use a few layers. 256 x 256 x 3 = 196,608 pixels.
3. Your convolutions masks is small you may use it for edges or contrast but for area you need more layers or middle sizes of the convolution networks too.
4. For the same tasks I added image masking for areas and regions you may try adjusting it value and compared with multiple outputs from convolution networks.

Sample: Input gray image & remarks ( prediction part is separated )

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
IMG_SHAPE = ( 256, 256, 1 ) 
tsk1_CLASSES_NUM = 2
initial_epochs = 5

PATH = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors_jpg\\train\\Pikaploy', '*.jpg')
PATH_2 = os.path.join('F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Actors_jpg\\train\\Candidt Kibt', '*.jpg')
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH)
files_2 = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(PATH_2)

list_file = []
list_file_actual = []
list_label = []
list_label_actual = [ 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Pikaploy', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt', 'Candidt Kibt' ]
for file in files.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image =  tf.io.decode_jpeg( image, channels=0, ratio=1, fancy_upscaling=True, try_recover_truncated=False, acceptable_fraction=1, dct_method='INTEGER_FAST', name="decode_jpeg" )
    
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [256,256], method='nearest')
    
    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    : Image Masking
    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    n_horizon = 64
    n_features = 16
    masking_layer = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=50, input_shape=(n_horizon, n_features))
    image = tf.constant( masking_layer(image)[:,:,0], shape=(1, 1, 256, 256, 1) )
    
    list_file.append(image)
    
    temp = tf.ones([ 1 ]).numpy() * 0
    list_label.append( temp )
    
for file in files_2.take(5):
    image = tf.io.read_file( file )
    image =  tf.io.decode_jpeg( image, channels=0, ratio=1, fancy_upscaling=True, try_recover_truncated=False, acceptable_fraction=1, dct_method='INTEGER_FAST', name="decode_jpeg" )
    
    list_file_actual.append(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [256, 256], method='nearest')
    
    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    : Image Masking
    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    n_horizon = 64
    n_features = 16
    masking_layer = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=50, input_shape=(n_horizon, n_features))
    image = tf.constant( masking_layer(image)[:,:,0], shape=(1, 1, 256, 256, 1) )
    
    list_file.append(image)
    temp = tf.ones([ 1 ]).numpy() * 9
    list_label.append( temp )
    
checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

number_of_images=1887;
nb_epoch=10;
batch_size=100;
# image shape = (256,256,3)

cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ ])
# define CNN model
cnn.add((tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 1))))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
# define LSTM model
model= tf.keras.models.Sequential([ ])
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(cnn, input_shape=(None, 256, 256, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(number_of_images))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 1, 256, 256, 1), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(tf.cast(list_label, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(10, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Tasks
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.fit(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10,validation_data=(dataset))
```

Output: Model complied, running over across optimum points try rescaling to attached some optimum points.

```
Epoch 1/10
2022-12-02 15:50:50.692326: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
10/10 [==============================] - 10s 86ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.3000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/10
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

[image: Sample]